# UNUserNotification that's delivered to the notification center not showing up on screen as a banner

Tags: ios, swift

I have a notification with the following request and category:

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title // a string
    content.body = body // a string
    content.sound = .default
    content.categoryIdentifier = "foo"

    UNNotificationRequest(
        identifier: UUID().uuidString,
        content: content,
        trigger: trigger // trigger scheduled some seconds in the future, repeats: false
    )

    UNNotificationCategory(
        identifier: content.categoryIdentifier,
        actions: actions,
        intentIdentifiers: [],
        options: .customDismissAction
    )
```

I schedule it some time in the future (x seconds) and it doesn't repeat. I have the following implementation of the `will present` delegate method:

```
public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                   willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                   withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState != .active {
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
}
```

This is to make sure the notification doesn't show up when the app is in the foreground (I have a modal to show if that's the case).

When the app is backgrounded and I make the notification fire, it shows up as a banner. When I open the phone's notification center I can also see it there. When the app is foregrounded I don't see the banner and it doesn't show up in the notification center. Exactly as intended. However, when the app is foregrounded and I schedule a notification, then minimize the app before the notification is delivered, I don't see the banner either, but it does show up in the notification center.

I'm wondering why does the notification get scheduled and delivered, but not shown as a banner? Is there any known bug regarding this? Is there some relevant code I might be missing? Basically I want any notification that's delivered to the notification center to also show as a banner, but it seems that when the app is minimized after scheduling and before delivery the banner doesn't show up.

Comment: What does minimized mean?

Comment: Also it is quite pointless  to require the banner, as the user can suppress it.

Comment: @matt minimized means backgrounded, not visible, etc. Pressing the home button / swiping up from the bottom of the screen. And it doesn't really matter if it's pointless, it's the spec that was provided to me. I don't make the decisions, I just execute. Our users are not typical users, you can't download our app in the store on your own and start using it, it's something that's provided to you via third party, it's part of a service those third parties provide.

Comment: Ok but when you do that your app is not backgrounded. Banners appear by default only when the app is backgrounded. You can set the delegate to ask the banner to appear when inactive.

Comment: @matt I know the banner is supposed to appear by default. The question is that it doesn't and I'm asking WHY.